# Geth Light Sync functionality

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, light-clients, fast-sync

If I use the light version of geth sync, can I make a token & deploy contracts using that? The light client "gets only the current state", from that point onwards or everytime I query the blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

The light version only has the current state meaning headers and other necessary information, but it needs a full node to operate in most cases.

You can deploy contracts and make tokens, but be aware the light client is in beta version, and for example I have experience that, although you can deploy the contract, it does not notify when the contract has been mined. It does get mined nevertheless.